# integrate php with drupal

Tags: drupal

How to include php pages in drupal without changing the php code so that dynamically content can be generated.Any process is ok.But i don't want to do the coding in drupal

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

enable PHP filter module, choose in Content adding time this filter, add php code - it's not drupal way, but faster to do...

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your PHP file is very secure as you're opening a potential hole in your Drupal system.
2. Activate the PHP Input filter for your admin editor profile. (Don't give untrusted users access to this editor!)
3. Edit your Content Item.
4. Add something like <?php include('/path/to/my/very/secure/file.php'); ?>
5. Save.